# How do I structure my project folder in eclipse for Cucumber project which has sprint wise delivery

Tags: frameworks, automation, cucumber

I am trying to create an automation framework using cucumber and trying to replicate a real time scenario (sprint wise delivery).
How do I structure my folders/source folders/packages in eclipse? Below is the structure which I am about to follow but I am not quite convinced if it is right.

[image]

I am trying to structure in such a way that when I give the command 
"mvn test -Dcucumber.options="src\test\resources\sprint1\features", then it should run all the features under sprint1, similarly for sprint2 and so on.
Any suggestions or inputs would be helpful.
P.S: Since I am new to cucumber, a detailed explaination on the folder structure for real time sprint wise delivery would be much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I would not consider the file structure you are thinking of.

The reason is that after a while, it doesn't matter when a feature was added to the system. So organizing features based on time is a bad idea.

If you still need to be able to run the features for a specific sprint, consider using tags instead. That would allow you only to run the features connected to the sprint you are interested in.

I would not to that either, because after a while it doesn't matter which sprint a piece of functionality was added. It should still pass all executions, even if it is 27 sprints old.

If this organization is bad, how should you do it instead?

This is a question where a lot of people have a lot of opinions and the debate can get very heated.

My take is that it is interesting to make sure that the code is easy to use. With that I mean easy to navigate and understand for a new developer. If you want, think of usability in any other product.

Given this, I would organize the features after functional areas in different packages. A package for each area, one for viewing products, one for ordering products, one for paying etc.

I would also try to take a step further and organize the source code in a similar way.

But I would never organize using a temporal approach as you are thinking of.

Comment: I agree with what you've written and likewise believe that a feature-oriented (as opposed to a time-oriented) organization of tests makes a lot of sense. Ultimately, when a given feature was developed will be of no practical consequence to developers in the future, but for sure those developers will have an interest in whether that feature's tests are all grouped together as concerns of that feature.

Answer (score 0):

You should not organize your tests as per the sprint because a particular sprint will end on a particular time. If you want to run some feature files together for temporary basis(till the time sprint is not over), you can add tags on the top in the feature files.

For example:
You have following 2 feature files:

1. src/test/resources/sprint1/file1.feature
2. src/test/resources/sprint1/file2.feature

Just add "@sprint1" on top of each feature as shown below:

```
//1. file1.feature
@sprint1
Feature: sprint1 : features : file1
Scenario: Some scenario desc..
Given ....
When ....
Then ....

//2. file2.feature
@sprint1
Feature: sprint1 : features : file1
Scenario: Some scenario desc..
Given ....
When ....
Then ....
```

Now to run these both files you need to execute the following code in your command prompt:

```
cucumber --tags @sprint1
```

By executing this command, all the files which contains "@sprint1" tag will run. After the sprint is over, you can delete this extra tag from feature files